# In haskell Conduit, how do I zip a Source that yields lists with one that doesn't

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm using `sourceFile` which yields `ByteString` and another source that yields `Word8`.  My `Word8` source is infinite.

I need a way to convert my `Word8` source to a `[Word8]` source where the lists are the same length as the `ByteString` from the first source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the context is for doing something like this, but the more straight-forward way would be to convert the ByteString Source into a Word8 Source, and then zip the two Word8 sources together. If you really needed to get back the original ByteStrings, you could include some marker to indicate end-of-chunk.

A more complicated approach would be to use connect-and-resume and manually deal with popping values out of the sources.